# Find object by partial match with another object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, immutable.js

I have the following data:

```
 let Collection = [{
    id: '1',
    uid: 'u1',
    rci: 'r1',
    name: 'ClientName'
  }, {
    uid: 'u2',
    name: 'ClientName 2'
  }, {
    rci: 'r3',
    name: 'ClientName 3'
  }]
```

id, uid and rci are three different id properties (result from terrible database merge).

Every client:

- Has at least one of these properties
- May have all three id

Now the question: 
I have to search this collection with an object that looks similar to this:

```
search: {
    id: undefined,
    uid: 'u3',
    rci: 'r3'
}
```

which matches the third entry in the collection, because the rci properties match.

Obviously, there's this solution:

```
let match;

let test = Collection.forEach(item => {
  Object.keys(search).forEach(key => {
    console.log('iteration')
    if(item[key] && item[key] === search[key]) {
        match = item
    }
  })
})
```

But I was looking for a little more elegant solution.
I'm also using underscorejs.

NOTE: This are POJO versions of Immutable.js collections/maps/lists. If the same thing is achievable with Immutable.js it would be great :)

Comment: *"`if(item[key] && item[key] === search[key]) {`"* None of your search values can ever be zero? (Or any other falsy value?)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder usually IDs can't be zero. But, bad DB, who knows...

Comment: Haven't checked if it will do for your requirements, but Underscore has an `IsMatch` function: http://underscorejs.org/#isMatch

Comment: @Me.Name: Nope, because his example `search` wouldn't match the third entry, as the third entry only has `rci` and not `uid` or `id`.

Answer (score 1):

In plain Javascript you can use [`Array#filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array#some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
function find(array, search) {
    var s = {};
    Object.keys(search).forEach(function (k) {
        if (typeof search[k] !== 'undefined') {
            s[k] = search[k];
        }
    });
    return array.filter(function (a) {
        return Object.keys(s).some(function (k) {
            return s[k] === a[k];
        });
    });
}

var collection = [{ id: '1', uid: 'u1', rci: 'r1', name: 'ClientName' }, { uid: 'u2', name: 'ClientName 2' }, { rci: 'r3', name: 'ClientName 3' }],
    result = find(collection, { id: undefined, uid: 'u3', rci: 'r3' });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your question right, the search should find something that matches **any** non-`undefined` key/value pair on the `search` object (rather than all).

If so, you can make that a bit more efficient by figuring out what those keys are *once*, and stopping looping once you find a match:

```
let keys = Object.keys(search).filter(key => search[key] !== undefined);
let match = _.find(Collection, item => keys.some(key => item[key] === search[key]));
```

As of ES2015 (aka ES6), or with a shim for `Array#find`, no Underscore would be needed:

```
let keys = Object.keys(search).filter(key => search[key] !== undefined);
let match = Collection.find(item => keys.some(key => item[key] === search[key]));
```

We don't need the `item[key] &&` you had because we filter out keys with `undefined` values before we start the search, so if the item doesn't have a key, `item[key]` won't be a `===` match for `search[key]`.

Here's a [**live example**](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=%20let%20Collection%20%3D%20%5B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20'1'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20uid%3A%20'u1'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20rci%3A%20'r1'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'ClientName'%0A%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20uid%3A%20'u2'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'ClientName%202'%0A%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20rci%3A%20'r3'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'ClientName%203'%0A%20%20%7D%5D%3B%0A%0Alet%20search%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20undefined%2C%0A%20%20%20%20uid%3A%20'u3'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20rci%3A%20'r3'%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Alet%20keys%20%3D%20Object.keys(search).filter(key%20%3D%3E%20search%5Bkey%5D%20!%3D%3D%20undefined)%3B%0Alet%20match%20%3D%20Collection.find(item%20%3D%3E%20keys.some(key%20%3D%3E%20item%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%3D%3D%20search%5Bkey%5D))%3B%0Aconsole.log(match)%3B) of the ES2015 version using your sample data on Babel's REPL.

Comment: just a short question regarding `search[key] !== undefined` vs `typeof search[k] !== 'undefined'`. what is better in this case?

Comment: @NinaScholz: I don't think it matters in today's world. The `undefined` global is now read-only. A **long** time ago, there was an issue with `undefined` in one window not being `===` `undefined` in another window. However, it's still (regrettably) possible to shadow the symbol `undefined`, so if you're writing a general-purpose library that may be executed within a scope you don't control where someone may have done something insane like `var undefined = 42`, you'd might want to defend against that. *(cont'd)*

Comment: *(continuing)* Usually in that case you have a scoping function anyway (so you can have lib-specific private globals), which provides an easy way to handle that defense: `(function(undefined) { ... })();` I always ensure that I can trust `undefined`, so I don't have to use the longer `typeof` check.